# How to remove from the list of objects those objects whose id is given in another list JAVA?

Tags: java, list

```
public class Person {
    private long id;
    private String name;
}
```

```
List<Person> persons= Arrays.asList(new Person(1,"Alex"),new Person(2,"Danny"),new Person(3,"Frank"));
List<Long>ids=Arrays.asList(1L,5L);
```

How to effectively remove objects from the list of persons whose id is on the list of ids?? 
The best way for me is to use streams.

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote solving this with streams?

Comment: I didn't solved yet.

Comment: If you post the code that doesn't work. someone may be able to help you *get* it to work.

Comment: This code is just the example to better understand what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Stream filter to filter the list based on your criteria.

```
List<Person> filteredPersons = persons.stream()
                                      .filter(person -> !ids.contains(person.id))
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This would be a good place to get you started on Streams
https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-map-filter-collect-of-stream-in-java-8

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alter the original list in-place, rather than making a copy, you can use the `removeIf()` method with a suitable predicate:

```
persons.removeIf(p -> !ids.contains(p.id));
```

Also note that using a `Set` for the `ids` collection will make your intent more obvious and probably perform better as the set of identifiers grows large.

Answer (score 0):

please check below code :-

```
package design.pattern;
public class Person {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    public Person(long id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


}

package design.pattern;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> persons= new ArrayList<Person>(Arrays.asList(new Person(1,"Alex"),new Person(2,"Danny"),new Person(3,"Frank")));
        List<Long>ids=Arrays.asList(1L,5L);

        for (int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
            Long id = persons.get(i).getId();
            System.out.println(id);
            if (ids.contains(id)) {
                System.out.println(id);
                persons.remove(persons.get(i));
            }
        }
        for(Person person:persons)
        System.out.println("Resultant List"+person.getName());
    }
}
```

hope this will be helpful for you